# Python "With" command detect nonexistent file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, exception, with-statement

If I want to use the "with" command in python to open a file, how can I detect a file being nonexistent and handle that case accordingly? (for example, if the filename is inputted by user, and the program needs to check if a file with the filename exists)
Also, How do I handle failures to open a file, for example a permission error or an error due to a corrupted file, using a python "With" statement?

Comment: what have you tried? Please see [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can't expect us to do your work for you.

Comment: Wrap it in a `try` block and catch the `FileNotFoundError`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can either wrap the whole block in a `try` block and catch `OSError` (the parent of all I/O and permission related errors in Python 3), or if you need to be absolutely sure it came from the `open`, and not another call in the block, `open` outside the `with` block, and immediately `with` it after verifying success.

Approach number 1:

```
try:
    with open(...) as f:
        ...
except OSError:
    ... handle error ...
```

or to only catch from the `open`:

```
try:
    f = open(...)
except OSError:
    ... handle error ...
else:
    # When the open succeeds, this is the very next thing executed, so
    # race window for stuff like Ctrl-C interrupting is tiny
    with f:
        ...
```

If you only want to catch a subset of [`OSError` subclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy), you can explicitly catch them one by one, or for uniform handling, catch a `tuple` of all recognized errors, e.g., to only catch non-existent file, is a directory, or permission related errors, while allowing other errors to bubble up, you could change:

```
except OSError:
```

to:

```
except (FileNotFoundError, IsADirectoryError, PermissionError):
```